# Using definition queries in GeoMedia Professional?

Tags: definition-query, geomedia

Does anyone know if GeoMedia 6.1 Professional has a selection feature that is equivalent to ESRI's ArcMap Definition Query function or anything similar to it?

Answer (score 2):

I had to Google Definition Query, and I understand it is a way to filter or mask certain objects from a feature class that has already been added to a map. (But maybe I am mistaken?)

As far as my knowledge goes there is not a tool that does exactly that in GeoMedia, although you can do pretty much the same by using Analysis / Attribute Query on your desired feature class, define your criteria using SQL and then add the result of that query to the legend.

You can then use Analysis / Queries to go back and edit the query as you like. The queries are dynamic, so the result is reflected instantly in the map window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Geomedia is great for querying.  The whole platform is built around querying really - even geoprocessing results are queries so as the source layer is updated the processing results (such as buffers) are also updated until they are output to a separate feature class.  This is great for drafting, and because geoprocessing queries can essentially be built into a chain which update dynamically there is no need to re-run processes when the source layer changes, or if you want to change the size of a buffer zone; you just edit the query.  In my opinion Geomedia does these basic things like querying, print layouts and feature styling a lot better than Arc - unfortunately I haven't used it deeply enough to know if it the same depth of tools.  I do however know that the basic tools that I think most users will use day to day are much more flexible and better organised.  Geomedia is an incredibly well thought out program, clearly designed and built from the top down compared to the sprawling mess that is Arc.